# Why did 10 GB of RAM disappear?

Tags: linux, debian, ram

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3-15ADA6 Laptop, Type 82KR, with Debian 11 Bullseye.

I have just installed a brand new RAM chip, Corsair Vengeance 8Gb DDR4 2400MHz, as from Lenovo specifications.

If I run `sudo lshw` I can see all the installed RAM correctly:

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 12GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
         product: CMSX8GX4M1A2400C16
         vendor: Unknown
         physical id: 0
         serial: 00000000
         slot: DIMM 0
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
         product: HMA851S6DJR6N-XN
         vendor: Hynix
         physical id: 1
         serial: 00000000
         slot: DIMM 0
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

I expected to have 12 GB of RAM, but if I run `htop`, the graphical system monitor or simply the `free` command, this is what I get:

```bash
$ free -ht
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2,8Gi       1,8Gi       260Mi        45Mi       713Mi       700Mi
Swap:          976Mi       973Mi       3,0Mi
Total:         3,8Gi       2,8Gi       264Mi
```

The system tends to freeze with a small number of open applications. I thought the memory might be broken, but I should be able to see 4 GB anyway, the amount of fixed installed memory on the motherboard, not 2.8 GB!

Comment: 32bit kernel? What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: You have completely rebooted (not just suspend)..?

Comment: No, the kernel is 64bit:

uname -a
Linux Lenovo-Mirko 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: How much does memtest86 detect? https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm Your kernel doesn't see even the full 4GB of RAM that you have. Something is wrong.

Comment: @roaima I think it is very difficult to change a RAM bank with the PC turned on ... so of course yes, I have completely stopped the system, open the case, unplug the battery, unload capacitors anf finally change the RAM. At last I started the system and the result is what you can see in the question.

Comment: Yes! That's why I contrasted with suspend to disk (hibernate)

Comment: @Artem S. The bios is reading correctly all the 12 GB of RAM, I'm flashing a pen drive for memtest86, when finished I'll add a comment

Comment: Also memtest read only 2.8 Gb, by the way I think it is correct because 1GB is used for the internal graphic card, so probably the 8 GB bank I buyed is not compatible! I cannot understend why the BIOS and lshw read 12Gb of installed RAM. I'll answer my question and close. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what [I've read](https://www.ipc-computer.eu/lenovo/notebook/ideapad-serie/3/ideapad-3-15ada6-82kr/), you should be using 8GB DDR4-RAM 3200MHz (PC4-25600) instead of the slower memory you've used

Comment: Can you guarantee that the linked site is trustworthy?

Comment: I can't guarantee that, no. Interestingly Crucial suggest this [8GB DDR4-2400 variant](https://uk.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-3-15ada6#memory)

Comment: That is what I saw yesterday. I get the 3200MHz variant, if it will not work I'll change with the 2400MHz variant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just for completeness, the Crucial 3200 MHz is fully compatible and now (at last) I can see and use about 12Gb RAM.

Comment: Thank you for passing that on. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the BIOS and lshw both read 12Gb of installed RAM, probably the Corsair 8Gb bank is not compatible with my model of Lenovo for some unknown reason. The system reads 2.8 Gb correctly because of 1Gb assigned to the internal graphic card.
Thanks to all and consider this post closed.

Comment: You can try running the PC with only this one 8GB RAM stick inside and see if it starts up. It might just be the configuration in which you added the RAM is not supported

Comment: No, I cannot because the Hynix 4Gb is welded on the motherboard. It's the only think of Lenovo systems that I really hate!